# Matrix for which $|a_{ii}| \leq \sum_{j\neq i} |a_{ij}|$ for all i.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), a matrix is said to be diagonally dominant if for every row of the matrix, the magnitude of the diagonal entry in a row is larger than or equal to the sum of the magnitudes of all the other (non-diagonal) entries in that row. More precisely, the matrix A is diagonally dominant if
$$|a_{ii}| \geq \sum_{j\neq i} |a_{ij}| \quad\text{for all } i, \,$$
where $a_{ij}$ denotes the entry in the i-th row and j-th column. What are the names, instead, the matrices that satisfy the inverse inequality? 
$$|a_{ii}| \leq \sum_{j\neq i} |a_{ij}| \quad\text{for all } i, \,$$
(If they have a name!)

Comment: Idk, Diagonally submissive perhaps :P

Comment: I have not heard about any special name for such a matrix, but 'off-diagonal dominant' would be a natural name to give it.

Comment: @Winther, thank you. I happened to work on some matrices that had this property and I thought they had a name.